# How does de-referencing work for pointer to an array?

Tags: c, pointers

Pointer to array of elements when dereferenced return an address.
Since it is holding the address of the first element of the array, dereferencing it should return a value.

```
int arr[] = { 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 }; 
int *p = arr; 
int (*ptr)[5] = &arr;     
printf("p = %p, ptr = %p\n", p, ptr); 
printf("*p = %d, *ptr = %p\n", *p, *ptr);
```

Output:

p = 0x7fff6ea72d10, ptr = 0x7fff6ea72d10

*p = 3, *ptr = 0x7fff6ea72d10

Why does *ptr return the base address of the array, shouldn't it return the value at that address??

Answer (score 7):

> Why does *ptr return the base address of the array, shouldn't it
>   return the value at that address??

(p3) Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `'&'` operator, or is a *string literal* used to initialize an array, an expression that has type *"array of type"* is converted to an expression with type *"pointer to type"* that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

```
int (*ptr)[5] = &arr;
```

`ptr` is a *pointer-to-array* of `int [5]`. When you dereference `ptr` you get *array of* `int[5]`. How is an array of `int[5]` accessed?

Rule `6.3.2.1` provides the answer:

> *"array of type"* is converted to an expression with type *"pointer to type"* that points to the initial element of the array object...

Now if you dereference again (e.g. `**ptr`), then you get the value of the 1st element.

Comment: as ptr stores the address of the first element of the array(as seen in the output) shouldn't dereferencing it return the value at that address?? How does compiler know not to return the value but the address??.

Comment: That is a matter of a difference in *type* not value. `ptr` is a *pointer-to-array*. When you dereference `ptr` (e.g. `*ptr`) you then have and array type `int[5]`. **Both** hold the **address of the first element**, but the first is of type **pointer-to-array** while the second is of type **array of int[5]**. So through levels of indirection, you access the object as differing types, but so long as there is still a level of indirection present, you do not access the value.

Comment: @Akash A compiler can see the target type is an array and  so forego the fetch of the target. It'd be quite dumb of it not to do that. Fetching a very large array just to drop it, returning the address you fetched from would be quite a waste.

Comment: Think of it this way, `ptr` holds the address of the first `int array[5]`. Then it becomes a matter what is `int array[5]`? `int array[5]` on access is the address.of the first element -- so both hold the same address, the address of the first element (but they are completely different types).

Answer (score 2):

The question was

> "Why does `*ptr` return the base address of the array, shouldn't it return the value at that address?"

It **does** return the value at that address, which is **the** array `arr`.

Think about a queue of people: you can point to the first person and say "that person over there" or you can point to the same person and say "that queue over there". There are *2* things at the same location: a person and a queue. Same thing happens with arrays: `person *` for that "person over there" and `person (*)[42]` "for that queue of 42 people". If you dereference a pointer to queue, you get a queue. If you take the first from the queue you get a person.

---

*But* then the array itself will decay to *address* to the *first* element when it is given as an argument to `printf`. Thus here,

```
int arr[] = { 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 }; 
int (*ptr)[5] = &arr;     

// undefined behaviour really, all pointers should be cast to void *
printf("%p %p %p %p", *ptr, &ptr[0], arr, &arr[0]);
```

all these 4 expressions will result in pointer to `int`, and the value is the address of the first element in the array (the address of 3 in `arr`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple, less technical explanation.

How are you setting `p`? `= arr;`

How are you setting `ptr`? `= &arr;`

Your question really has nothing to do with arrays at all. `arr` could be literally any type and the answer would be the same: `&` gets the address of `arr`, so whatever `arr` is, `ptr` is storing its address while `p` is storing `arr` itself.

If you do `*ptr`, you will dereference that address and thus get a value equal to `p`.

```
int arr = 3;
// clearly these are different!
int p = arr;
int* ptr = &arr;
```

Similarly

```
int x = 3;
int* arr = &x;
// clearly these are different!
int* p = arr;
int** ptr = &arr;
// so of course they dereference differently
printf("*p = %d, *ptr = %p\n", *p, *ptr);
```

Answer (score -1):

The behavior you see is a result of 'c' interpreting `arr` as a pointer to the memory location of the first element. Pointer to the array `&arr` will be an address of the array itself in memory, which is also the address of its first element. As a result `arr` and `&arr` yield the same values. Try this:

```
printf("array = %p, &array = %p\n", arr, &arr);
```

Thought the values are the same, types are different. `arr` is a variable, whether `&arr` is a pointer to the variable.

`ptr` reflects the same picture. Its value `ptr = &arr` makes it a pointer to an array. It contains the address of the array. `*ptr` returns the array itself, which in 'c' interpretation is the address of the first element of the array. As a result values for `ptr` and `*ptr` are the same as for `&arr` and `arr`.

Hope it makes it clearer (not murkier) :-)

Answer (score -3):

Arrays are pointers. **Arrays are not pointers, see the comments below**

A pointer to an array is a pointer, pointing at a pointer. Try de-referencing twice over, that should yeild a value.

Comment: "Arrays are pointers." No, they're not. They just decay to pointers in many contexts.

Comment: The difference being?

Comment: an array is not a pointer but a container, you will not surprised by the fact sizeof(arr) != sizeof(p)  (_p_ is a pointer) isn't it ? Is just in some contexts an array is used as a pointer, for instance given in argument to a function

Comment: One important difference would be the size: `sizeof(T[N])` is equal to `N * sizeof(T)` whereas `sizeof(T*)` will be equal to the size of any other pointer. Then, you can't reassign arrays, but you can reassign pointers. Also an array of arrays is contiguous in memory, but an array of pointers would contain pointers that point somewhere else.

Comment: @sepp2k except that pointers to distinct types need not be of equal size.